# Bottombar but minSdk 19 to develop nice UI [android]

Tags: android

I am working on application i want to use bottombar in my app .but my app should support minSdk 19 .but bottom bar is used for minsdk 23 if i am correct ?how to design UI

Comment: try setting the tab layout gravity bottom.And try to provide some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works even with **minSdk 15** (for bottomNavigationView) [see this for help](https://tutorialwing.com/android-bottom-navigation-view-tutorial-with-example/).

You could also use **awesome custom styled bottomBar** which works even with ***minSdk 11 !!*** [See this!](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar)

There are a lot of tutorials on YouTube [for bottomBar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcyKDTQ772I) & [for bottomNavigationView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcE7IIHKfRg) and many more!